# How can I visualize the distribution of authorships?

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-science, diagram

I'm currently looking at [dblp](https://dblp.uni-trier.de/), a database of scientific publications. More specifically, I look at the authors.

Ignoring the problem of non-unique names, you can see that some authors are on many publications:

```
1181x H. Vincent Poor
 789x Lajos Hanzo
 767x Witold Pedrycz
 747x Mohamed-Slim Alouini
 615x Chin-Chen Chang 0001
 607x Dacheng Tao
 591x Victor C. M. Leung
 570x Wei Zhang
 562x Wei Li
 554x Wei Wang
```

Ignoring multiple authors in one publication for the moment, I counted how often authors in the database have 1,2, 3, ..., 1181 publications. I want to understand this distribution:

```
count_of_counts = {1: 785070, 2: 239357, 3: 117040, 4: 70321, 5: 46957, 6: 33814, 7: 25141, 8: 19546, 9: 15821, 10: 13013, 11: 10615, 12: 8927, 13: 7622, 14: 6694, 15: 5973, 16: 5234, 17: 4673, 18: 4116, 19: 3653, 20: 3257, 21: 3062, 22: 2671, 23: 2516, 24: 2297, 25: 2182, 26: 1879, 27: 1775, 28: 1649, 29: 1584, 30: 1467, 31: 1326, 32: 1265, 34: 1170, 33: 1153, 35: 1038, 36: 977, 37: 900, 38: 872, 39: 807, 40: 727, 41: 691, 42: 670, 43: 611, 44: 592, 45: 585, 46: 573, 47: 549, 49: 509, 48: 478, 51: 465, 50: 456, 52: 419, 53: 398, 56: 364, 55: 352, 54: 346, 57: 315, 60: 304, 59: 294, 58: 290, 62: 267, 61: 260, 63: 249, 68: 220, 65: 211, 72: 205, 69: 205, 67: 205, 64: 204, 71: 198, 66: 191, 70: 182, 77: 169, 74: 164, 73: 161, 76: 155, 75: 152, 79: 140, 81: 132, 78: 127, 86: 122, 80: 120, 82: 115, 89: 111, 87: 108, 85: 106, 83: 105, 84: 96, 88: 91, 94: 84, 91: 81, 93: 79, 90: 79, 92: 78, 96: 76, 97: 73, 101: 71, 100: 70, 98: 70, 95: 69, 99: 67, 107: 64, 102: 61, 115: 58, 106: 58, 105: 56, 110: 54, 112: 52, 104: 52, 103: 49, 109: 48, 117: 46, 114: 46, 108: 46, 118: 44, 116: 40, 111: 40, 129: 39, 122: 37, 113: 36, 133: 32, 143: 30, 120: 30, 119: 30, 130: 29, 128: 29, 125: 29, 124: 29, 121: 28, 138: 27, 136: 27, 131: 27, 126: 27, 155: 24, 123: 24, 146: 23, 144: 23, 137: 23, 127: 23, 139: 22, 142: 21, 140: 21, 132: 21, 134: 20, 141: 19, 149: 18, 145: 18, 135: 18, 158: 17, 162: 16, 152: 16, 151: 16, 187: 15, 165: 15, 147: 15, 169: 14, 167: 14, 164: 14, 157: 14, 154: 14, 150: 14, 148: 14, 163: 13, 156: 13, 189: 12, 188: 12, 161: 12, 160: 12, 204: 11, 181: 11, 153: 11, 206: 10, 177: 10, 176: 10, 159: 10, 222: 9, 197: 9, 190: 9, 180: 9, 175: 9, 173: 9, 220: 8, 219: 8, 210: 8, 196: 8, 195: 8, 193: 8, 191: 8, 182: 8, 179: 8, 178: 8, 174: 8, 170: 8, 168: 8, 166: 8, 245: 7, 221: 7, 217: 7, 202: 7, 186: 7, 185: 7, 171: 7, 259: 6, 233: 6, 227: 6, 214: 6, 213: 6, 212: 6, 203: 6, 200: 6, 198: 6, 194: 6, 183: 6, 172: 6, 250: 5, 243: 5, 235: 5, 224: 5, 223: 5, 218: 5, 216: 5, 208: 5, 207: 5, 192: 5, 184: 5, 318: 4, 303: 4, 299: 4, 285: 4, 282: 4, 279: 4, 273: 4, 260: 4, 252: 4, 249: 4, 239: 4, 237: 4, 232: 4, 229: 4, 209: 4, 201: 4, 383: 3, 380: 3, 377: 3, 366: 3, 364: 3, 354: 3, 317: 3, 311: 3, 301: 3, 298: 3, 294: 3, 287: 3, 272: 3, 265: 3, 264: 3, 257: 3, 253: 3, 251: 3, 248: 3, 247: 3, 244: 3, 242: 3, 238: 3, 236: 3, 228: 3, 226: 3, 215: 3, 211: 3, 205: 3, 199: 3, 518: 2, 463: 2, 449: 2, 390: 2, 365: 2, 351: 2, 350: 2, 349: 2, 341: 2, 331: 2, 322: 2, 321: 2, 320: 2, 315: 2, 312: 2, 310: 2, 306: 2, 304: 2, 292: 2, 289: 2, 288: 2, 286: 2, 284: 2, 277: 2, 275: 2, 274: 2, 271: 2, 270: 2, 268: 2, 266: 2, 263: 2, 261: 2, 258: 2, 255: 2, 246: 2, 230: 2, 225: 2, 1181: 1, 789: 1, 767: 1, 747: 1, 615: 1, 607: 1, 591: 1, 570: 1, 562: 1, 554: 1, 541: 1, 529: 1, 526: 1, 522: 1, 521: 1, 515: 1, 513: 1, 502: 1, 488: 1, 485: 1, 475: 1, 466: 1, 461: 1, 459: 1, 457: 1, 455: 1, 452: 1, 446: 1, 435: 1, 432: 1, 430: 1, 429: 1, 409: 1, 407: 1, 405: 1, 403: 1, 391: 1, 388: 1, 386: 1, 385: 1, 384: 1, 379: 1, 374: 1, 372: 1, 369: 1, 367: 1, 362: 1, 361: 1, 360: 1, 357: 1, 356: 1, 355: 1, 345: 1, 339: 1, 337: 1, 335: 1, 333: 1, 332: 1, 329: 1, 327: 1, 326: 1, 325: 1, 324: 1, 323: 1, 319: 1, 316: 1, 314: 1, 308: 1, 305: 1, 302: 1, 300: 1, 296: 1, 293: 1, 290: 1, 283: 1, 281: 1, 280: 1, 278: 1, 269: 1, 267: 1, 254: 1, 240: 1, 234: 1, 231: 1}
```

We have `len(count_of_counts) = 392`.

In this dict you can see that 785,070 authors have only made one publication.

**How can I visualize this distribution?**

### My Attempt

I thought about a simple histogram, but that would hide that the author "H. Vincent Poor" is in some sense "equivalent" to 1181 authors who only had one publication.

Then I thought about a bar chart where I group the 392 groups to up to 10 groups. The split should be chosen in a way that the groups are of similar size. With the given numbers, that would be (392-1) nCr (10 - 1) \approx 10^17 possible splits. So way too many to find the "best" by brute force. While I could imagine how to do this, I would first like to know if one of the common visualization libraries already does something similar.

---

I would like to create a plot like this:

[image]

I don't know how this kind of chart is called. I have seen it being used for US budget visualizations. It is a variation of a pie chart and should have the following properties:

- Label: The first number is the important one. The "1" in my example is the number of publications the group has. The second number is how many people fall in that group.
- The size of the group (the size of the colored rectangles) is how much of the whole the group is.

  - For the "1" group, it is simply the number of authors
  - For the "2" group, it is 2x the number of authors in the group
  - For the 4-5 group, it is 4x the number of authors who had 4 publications + 5x the number of authors who had 5 publications.
- The groups (1 publication, 2 publications, 3 publications, 4-5 publications, ...) should be chosen in such a way that they have a reasonable size in the diagram.
- Only "neighboring" groups may be joined (e.g. "4" and "5").

I would prefer to do this with [python](/questions/tagged/python), maybe with [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) or [seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn), but I'm not sure if that (or something similar) is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are called [`Treemaps`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping). I did find a python implementation [`here`](https://github.com/laserson/squarify).

```
# pip install squarify
import squarify
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# custom light colors
colors = ['#FFF2CD', '#D9E8FB', '#FFE6CD', '#F7CECC', '#D5E8D4', 'lightgrey', 'lightblue']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
squarify.plot(sizes=count_of_counts.values(), label=count_of_counts.keys(), 
              color=colors, bar_kwargs={'edgecolor':'lightblue','linewidth': 2}, 
              ax=ax, value=count_of_counts.values())

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: Treemap]